# How to migrate from a MySQL master-slave setup to a master-master setup without downtime

Tags: mysql, replication, multi-master

We have an existing master-slave MySQL replication setup where we would like to promote the second slave to a master in order to achieve a master-master setup with no or only minimal downtime.

Is it sufficient to do a `SHOW MASTER STATUS` on the slave and do a `CHANGE MASTER TO ...` on the current master or will this result in a replication error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a basic level, yes. Just set up the current Master like you would any normal slave database.

However, there are some things to consider first.

Is the second slave set to `READ-ONLY`, as you want to avoid writing to both masters at once.

You probably want to set `auto_increment_increment=2` and `auto_increment_offset=1` on the first master, and `auto_increment_increment=2` and `auto_increment_offset=2` on the second master.

This prevents the two masters from creating the same auto_increment primary keys.

You also want to make sure you have no replication filters (binlog-do-db, replicate-do-db etc) set up as they can cause problems too).

Comment: Also `log_slave_updates` and `log_bin`.